# Asking students to define "unique"

Tags: undergraduate-education, assessment

Context: This is for introductory linear algebra course, near the beginning.

As a sort of "exit survey" after one of my lectures, I would like to ask my students to try and define what "unique" is from a mathematical perspective. I would then talk about that next time. However, I am not sure

1. whether that's a good idea; or
2. how to phrase the question so that I don't get answers like "it means you're really special".

Comment: @Namaste I want this to be more of a "pre-assessment" prior to discussing unique solutions

Comment: This question greatly confuses me, since **uni-** means "one".  Ergo, a function with a unique solution is (no pun intended) one with **one** solution.

Comment: To follow up: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unique "**being the only one**".  It's my experience that mathematicians and scientists use existing words with defined meanings.

Comment: What is this "exit survey" for? Does it contribute to the grade?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni it’s a preassessment, so it’s not for credit

Comment: @RonJohn While I agree that it is good to look to colloquial or vernacular English when trying to decipher the meaning of a term in mathematics, I think that it is overly reductive to say that "...mathematicians and scientists use existing words with defined meanings."  Aside from the fact that this is somewhat tautological, mathematicians often use words which have vernacular meaning which is distinct from the technical meaning in mathematics.  For example:  even and odd, normal,  image, space, etc.

Comment: @XanderHenderson definitely **not** colloquial and vernacular English.  That's where twaddle like "it means you're really special" comes from.  Latin, Greek and traditional English definitions are what to look at.

Comment: @RonJohn And yet you cite a dictionary of vernacular English...  And please, pray tell:  how will Latin, Greek, and "traditional" English (whatever you mean by that) help to define "image" or "normal" in mathematical context?  Again, it is reasonable to *start* by looking at where a word comes from and how it is used outside of mathematics, but this isn't the end of the story.

Comment: @XanderHenderson "And yet you cite a dictionary of vernacular English..."  How so?  The third M-W definition of "unique" (being "unusual") is modern/colloquial, but "being the only one" is based directly on the Latin "one".

Comment: @XanderHenderson as far as "image", I can definitely see how the mathematical usage comes from the definitions of "image".  Ditto "normal", which has the Latin root meaning "carpenter's square".

Comment: The point, @RonJohn, is that MW is a dictionary of modern English, as it is spoken and written today (more or less---there is some lag).  If you are claiming that one should look to Latin or Greek roots, you should be citing a dictionary which actually invests some space to etymology.  The OED is probably the best English-language reference.  I'll also note that I have not argued that MW does a poor job of defining "unique" for a mathematician, only that MW (and the OED, and any other nontechnical dictionary) is *not* going to do the job for many other terms in mathematics.

Comment: @Namaste you're also using modern definitions instead of their roots. The root of "rational" is **ratio**.  Transcendental numbers transcend ("be or go beyond the range or limits of what can be defined with a ratio") the real, and the term "right angle" derives from the Latin for "up**right** angle".

Comment: @Namaste bottom line: mathematicians don't just make up new definitions for words.  **They extend existing definitions.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To avoid misinterpretations, I'd give it to them in a mathematical sentence and ask them to explain what they believe 'unique' means in this context.

For lack of knowing where you are in the course, I might give them an exit ticket such as

> Consider the sentence, "The equation $x^3 - 2x + 3 = 0$ has a unique
>   solution." What do you think the word "unique" means in this context?
>   Contrast this with the ways you might use "unique" in standard
>   English.

However, this sentence has a problem in that the word 'unique' can meaningfully only be interpreted in one way (or perhaps I'm uncreative); perhaps give them a mathematical sentence which is not quite so obvious.

Comment: Context matters.

Comment: Why would  mathematical usage be any different from normal language usage?  The dictionary meaning is quite clear -- exactly one of a kind, no other such item.  I'm fully (and sorrowfully) aware that many people misuse the word, e.g., "this is a very unique..."

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Although the use of 'unique' in this way is related to 'singular' which has the same literal meaning, but has been used to mean "special" rather than necessarily "unique" since at least the 19th century.

Comment: @Cubic and that usage is still wrong

Comment: The point is to have students analyze *their* use of language. Would writing "colloquial" English instead of "standard" English satisfy you?

Comment: @OpalE Honestly, I wouldn't be surprised if the word "colloquial" confuses more students than it helps, as students may not know what it means.  Perhaps "Contrast this with the ways that people use 'unique' when they speak or write English in an informal or nonmathematical setting," or "Contrast this with the ways that you use 'unique' in non-mathematical contexts," or something similar.

Comment: @Xander Henderson Oh, I agree. I'm objecting to pedantry. I like your rephrases though.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: See sense 3 in ["unique" (*Merriam-Webster*)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unique). It's not wrong, it's in the dictionary.

Comment: @Kevin lots of absolute crap is in the dictionary these days - dictionaries are the ultimate in knee-jerk concession to common misusage.  M-W even accepts use of "comprised of"

Answer (score 2):

I think that a linear algebra course is the perfect venue to have students develop their understanding of the mathematical concept of "uniqueness." A formative assignment such as the one you suggest is a good, initial step.

Later on, as the course progresses, students might even come to appreciate the mathematical phrase *unique up to unique isomorphism*.

Here is an example in linear algebra. A vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $k$ is unique, because any two such objects are isomorphic by a linear transformation. However, they are not unique up to unique isomorphism. If instead, you work in the category of finite dimensional **vectors spaces with an ordered  basis** over a fixed field $k$, then two vector spaces of the same dimension are unique up to unique isomorphism.